# how to add a mouseover event on Ext.data.JsonStore?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, extjs

I am stuck with a problem where in a Ext.form.ComboBox displays data by making an ajax call in beforequery listener and then populating the JSON object ABCD.data.TitleSuggest.

```
    var titleEditCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    store: ABCD.data.TitleSuggest,
    displayField: 'for_display', emptyText:'Please type a title',
    lazyRender:true, typeAhead:false, forceSelection:true, selectOnFocus:true, autoSelect:false, resizable:true,
    triggerAction: 'all', mode: 'remote', minChars:3, queryDelay:750, listWidth:550, listClass:'ab-combo-title',
    listEmptyText: 'No titles found',
    listeners: {
        beforequery: beforeTitleComboQuery,
        select:Portlet.onTitleSelect
    }

});
```

Now this JSON store uses use load event to process data and then dispay using ABCP.templates.tpl_title.apply.

```
ABCD.data.TitleSuggest = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
root:'XYZ',
totalProperty :'XYX',
fields: [
    {name:'xxx',        mapping:'xxx'},
    {name:'yyy',            mapping:'yyy'},
    {name:'for_display',        mapping:'for_display'}
],
baseParams: {"start":1, "limit":2, "titleTypes": [""]},
url: ABCP.Url.SuggestTitles,
listeners: {
    load: function(oStore, ayRecords, oOptions){
        oStore.each(function(){

            this.set('for_display', ABCP.templates.tpl_title.apply([
                this.xxx,
                this.yyy
            ]));

        });

    },

}
});
```

I want to display some additional data on mouseover of values xxx and yyy displayed in combo box(values are set using json store, we are supposed to modify the store to include few additional fields). I am not able to provide this mouseover functionality on already displayed values xxx and yyy.
These new values from store should be displayed on mouse over of existing values.

Please help me guys i am unable to add mouseover event  for specific data displayed in combo box.

I hope my ques is clear??

Comment: It looks like you are using some distribution for version 3 of Ext. They have a [sample for this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/examples/form/combos.html) using version 3.3.1 (the second combo in the page).

Comment: Using the `tpl` config property as show in the sample I linked does works for you?

Answer (score 0):

For Ext.ComboBox to work properly you need to define '**valueField**', which is a mandatory/required config, I don't see it specified in the config.

Please provide more details, or sencha fiddle code if defining 'valueField' doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: I am using version 3.4.0 for my application and it seems to work fine. I just want to add functionality on mousehover of data displayed in combobox.